# Azure Devops Pipeline - Create documentation from IaC file

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I currently have written a script that essentially takes in a .bicep file or Arm template file and creates a readme.md from this file with information like parameters/outputs/descriptions etc.

I want to automate this documentation creation somehow in an Azure DevOps pipeline, so whenever a new Bicep file is created, a corresponding readme.md also gets created. Does anyone know if this is possible using Azure DevOps pipelines and have any idea where to start? The script that creates the documentation is written in Python.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi dan, what's the latest status of your isse? has my post helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps for you to get the bicep file and transfer the content to Json

**Step 1**

You could refer to this document [Run MsBuild to Convert .Bicep File to .Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/msbuild-bicep-file?tabs=dotnet#run-msbuild) for the method

1.Open a Visual Studio Code terminal session.

2.In the PowerShell session, go to the C:\bicep-msbuild-demo directory.

3.Run MSBuild.
`MSBuild.exe -restore.\bicep-msbuild-demo.csproj`

The `restore` parameter creates dependencies needed to compile the Bicep file during the initial build. The parameter is optional after the initial build.

4.Go to the output directory and open the main.json file that should look like the sample.

**Step 2**

And then you could run the command below to get the json content from the file.

```
def get_json_content_of_specific_route_in_array(json_file_path, json_route):

    length = len(json_route)

    print(length)

   
    #open json file

    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:

        data = json.load(f)

        content = data

        #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]

        for i in range(length):

            if i == 0:

                content = data[json_route[i]]

            else:

                content = content[json_route[i]]

       
        #get the content

        return content
```

After that you could create the readme.md with the content and push to your repo